# Pushing sketches to pro mini with Uno 101

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-pro-mini

So I just bought a Pro Mini the other day, however, I didn't get an FTDI cable or a USB/Serial converter board.
From what I understand from this [article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Uploading-sketches-to-Pro-Mini-using-Arduino-UNO-b/) I can use my Arduino Uno 101 to push sketches onto the Pro Mini.

The wires are all hooked up (grounded reset on the Uno) and I have uploaded the sketch to disable the serial communication port on the Uno, however, when I try to push a sketch to the Mini it errors out with the following message

```
Arduino: 1.8.3 (Windows Store 1.8.6.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini, 
ATmega328 (5V, 16 MHz)"

Sketch uses 928 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for 
local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM3": The system cannot find the 
file specified.


Problem uploading to board.  
See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

The only part of the suggested troubleshooting guide that maybe applicable is the drivers section.

> Drivers
>
> The Arduino Uno and Mega 2560 use standard drivers (USB CDC) provided by the operating system to communicate with the ATmega8U2 on the board. Other Arduino boards use FTDI drivers to communicate with the FTDI chip on the board (or in the USB-serial convertor).

I could be wrong but to me it doesn't seem like the second sentence applies to this situation since the the Uno sits between the pc and the mini. However, when I check the windows device manager I can see that the Uno is connected on a COM port, but nothing about the Mini. Though I am not sure that it should show up.

I am using the IDE(1.8.3) to program and "Arduino Pro or Pro Mini" as the board. Though Tools>Port is greyed out when I have this board selected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Arduino Uno 101" there are only ["Arduino Uno"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and ["Arduino 101"](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoard101).

101 uses completely different hardware, and tricks to use an Uno as an USB to UART adapter won't work on an 101.

101 has also separate serial interfaces for USB serial (`Serial`) and hardware serial (`Serial1`).

If you have have an Arduino 101 you can solve this by software means.
The board needs to be able to change the baud rate and use DTR for reset.

There is a [sketch from PaulStoffregen](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/3343#issuecomment-115045979) on GitHub that does that.

```
/* USB to Serial - Teensy becomes a USB to Serial converter
   http://dorkbotpdx.org/blog/paul/teensy_as_benito_at_57600_baud

   You must select Serial from the "Tools > USB Type" menu

   This example code is in the public domain.
*/

// set this to the hardware serial port you wish to use
#define HWSERIAL Serial1

unsigned long baud = 19200;
const int reset_pin = 4;
const int led_pin = 13;  // 13 = Teensy 3.X & LC
                         // 11 = Teensy 2.0
                         //  6 = Teensy++ 2.0
void setup()
{
  pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(reset_pin, HIGH);
  pinMode(reset_pin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(baud);       // USB, communication to PC or Mac
  HWSERIAL.begin(baud);     // communication to hardware serial
}

long led_on_time=0;
byte buffer[80];
unsigned char prev_dtr = 0;

void loop()
{
  unsigned char dtr;
  int rd, wr, n;

  // check if any data has arrived on the USB virtual serial port
  rd = Serial.available();
  if (rd > 0) {
    // check if the hardware serial port is ready to transmit
    wr = HWSERIAL.availableForWrite();
    if (wr > 0) {
      // compute how much data to move, the smallest
      // of rd, wr and the buffer size
      if (rd > wr) rd = wr;
      if (rd > 80) rd = 80;
      // read data from the USB port
      n = Serial.readBytes((char *)buffer, rd);
      // write it to the hardware serial port
      HWSERIAL.write(buffer, n);
      // turn on the LED to indicate activity
      digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
      led_on_time = millis();
    }
  }

  // check if any data has arrived on the hardware serial port
  rd = HWSERIAL.available();
  if (rd > 0) {
    // check if the USB virtual serial port is ready to transmit
    wr = Serial.availableForWrite();
    if (wr > 0) {
      // compute how much data to move, the smallest
      // of rd, wr and the buffer size
      if (rd > wr) rd = wr;
      if (rd > 80) rd = 80;
      // read data from the hardware serial port
      n = HWSERIAL.readBytes((char *)buffer, rd);
      // write it to the USB port
      Serial.write(buffer, n);
      // turn on the LED to indicate activity
      digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
      led_on_time = millis();
    }
  }

  // check if the USB virtual serial port has raised DTR
  dtr = Serial.dtr();
  if (dtr && !prev_dtr) {
    digitalWrite(reset_pin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(250);
    digitalWrite(reset_pin, HIGH);
  }
  prev_dtr = dtr;

  // if the LED has been left on without more activity, turn it off
  if (millis() - led_on_time > 3) {
    digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
  }

  // check if the USB virtual serial wants a new baud rate
  if (Serial.baud() != baud) {
    baud = Serial.baud();
    if (baud == 57600) {
      // This ugly hack is necessary for talking
      // to the arduino bootloader, which actually
      // communicates at 58824 baud (+2.1% error).
      // Teensyduino will configure the UART for
      // the closest baud rate, which is 57143
      // baud (-0.8% error).  Serial communication
      // can tolerate about 2.5% error, so the
      // combined error is too large.  Simply
      // setting the baud rate to the same as
      // arduino's actual baud rate works.
      HWSERIAL.begin(58824);
    } else {
      HWSERIAL.begin(baud);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to connect:

```
Arduino 101  |  Arduino Pro Mini
-------------+------------------
VCC          |  VCC
GND          |  GND
TX           |  RX
RX           |  TX
PIN 4        |  DTR
```

After that you can use the port as a Arduino Pro Mini programmer.

Comment: I tested that code on a Pro Micro and was able to program a Pro Mini.